# For loop deleting rows doesn't work, need to run macro multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

*Working Environment: Excel 2013

Target: Delete the unnecessary columns by filtering the content in row 2.*

My idea is that as long as the content in row 2 is either

- `Physical Location` or
- `PLC Tag Name` or
- `Test Step1/2/3/4/5/6/7`,

keep those columns, otherwise delete it.

My problem is that I need to run this macro multiple times to delete all the unnecessary columns. It should loop from 1 to 40, and just leave the columns that I want. I am not sure why it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

My code:

```
Sub Reorder()
    Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

    For i = 1 To 40
        WY = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(2, i)
        Select Case WY
            Case "Physical Location"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "PLC Tag Name"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step1"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step2"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step3"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step4"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step5"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step6"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case "Test Step7"
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case Else
                Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 0
        End Select
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 40
        If Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 0 Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop from 40 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete rows in a loop, you need to start from the bottom. Otherwise the row number of the rows below the actual deleted row decrease by one and `i` gets increased by one (from the loop), so in sum you miss a line.

instead of

```
For i = 1 To 40
```

use

```
For i = 40 To 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, i) = 0 Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next
```

to loop backwards.

---

**Side note:** (thx to @A.S.H)
You should use full qualified ranges/cells/rows/columns and never assume the worksheet. Also declare all your variables using option explicit.

Therefore

```
Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
'...
Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
```

should be

```
Worksheets("Sheet4").Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
'...
Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
```

So in sum we end up at

```
Option Explicit 'first line in module

Public Sub Reorder()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WY As Worksheet

    Set WY = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    WY.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

    For i = 1 To 40
        Select Case WY.Cells(2, i)
            Case "Physical Location", "PLC Tag Name", "Test Step1", "Test Step2", _
                 "Test Step3", "Test Step4", "Test Step5", "Test Step6", "Test Step7"
                WY.Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case Else
                WY.Cells(1, i) = 0
        End Select
    Next i

    For i = 40 To 1 Step -1
        If WY.Cells(1, i) = 0 Then
            WY.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Or if we use only one loop which is a lot faster:

```
Option Explicit 'first line in module

Public Sub Reorder()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WY As Worksheet

    Set WY = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    WY.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

    For i = 40 To 1 Step -1
        Select Case WY.Cells(2, i)
            Case "Physical Location", "PLC Tag Name", "Test Step1", "Test Step2", _
                 "Test Step3", "Test Step4", "Test Step5", "Test Step6", "Test Step7"
                WY.Cells(1, i) = 1
            Case Else
                WY.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for completeness; qualify the first line `Worksheets("Sheet4").Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown` ( to avoid another question ;) )

Comment: @Peh Thanks! I don't even realize that I need to loop backwards. Now I know.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you too! Keeping a good practice in the beginning is always good to everyone.  thanks again to you two!

Comment: Hah and still place for improvements; I just realized that it is totally unnecessary to have 2 loops so we can reduce run time a lot. So maybe you can even omit writing the `1` into column 1 if this was just a helper column.